# EF Core Code-First: Seed Data but Ignore Constraints

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

In my application I have a User entity which has self-reference properties for creator and updater named 'CreatedBy' and 'UpdatedBy'. These properties are mandatory for each new user within the application, which means some constraints were introduced in my DB (I am using code-first approach).

The problem I have is that I want to be able to seed some initial data in my application where CreatedBy and UpdatedBy should be set to null (meaning the initial users have no creator of course). Is there some way to ignore/violate these constraints? Are there any workarounds?

How I am trying to seed data is by using the modelBulider's HasData() method.

Comment: In this case, `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` should be nullable. You can control these constraints programatically in your code so you don't insert anything null.

Comment: I think it's analysis bug. You must add administration account in modelMuilder HasData() method and wrtie this account to CreateBy and UpdatedBy. There is no way to control constraints like you want.